# Angular - *ngFor only returning one record from the array, despite 12 being available

Tags: java, angular

I am using HttpClient in Angular to retrieve data from an API endpoint I have created using SpringBoot.

I have created a service in Angular to consume the data. I am printing the data to the console, so I know the data is coming back.

I am trying to pass all of the outputs to a dropdown list, but despite using *ngFor, only 1 result is ever being returned:

Here is the code in the HTML file for the dropdown:

```
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-select
    placeholder="Select Competition">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let comp of competitionsList; let i = index" [value]="comp">
        {{ comp[i].name }}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
```

When I change the value of [i] to or [11] (the last element in my array) for testing purposes, all the data always displays as expected, but when I use comp[i].name I would have expected all elements in the array to be returned, but it is only returning the first element.

I'm sure it is something quite simple, but I have been looking at this for a long time and still cannot quite see why this is happening so any help will be greatly appreciated!

JSON Response: 
[{…}]

```
0:
0: {id: 2013, name: "Série A"}
1: {id: 2021, name: "Premier League"}
2: {id: 2016, name: "Championship"}
3: {id: 2001, name: "UEFA Champions League"}
4: {id: 2018, name: "European Championship"}
5: {id: 2015, name: "Ligue 1"}
6: {id: 2002, name: "Bundesliga"}
7: {id: 2019, name: "Serie A"}
8: {id: 2003, name: "Eredivisie"}
9: {id: 2017, name: "Primeira Liga"}
10: {id: 2014, name: "Primera Division"}
11: {id: 2000, name: "FIFA World Cup"}
ident: "competitions"
name: "com"
```

**Adding additional info:

I have defined an interface for the values which will be returned by the API:

```
export interface Competitions {
  id: number;
  name: string;
}
```

This is my service:

```
  retrieveAvailableCompetitions() {
    return this.http.get<Competitions>(this.competitionsUrl);
  }
```

And this is my method in TypeScript file:

```
getCompetitons() {
  this.service.retrieveAvailableCompetitions().pipe(
    map(responseData => {
      const compsList: Competitions[] = [];
      for (const key in responseData) {
        if (responseData.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
          compsList.push({ ...responseData[key], ident: key, name: 'com' });
        }
      }
      return compsList;
    })
  ).subscribe(
    compsList => {
      this.competitionsList = compsList;
      console.log(compsList);
    });
  }
```

(I'm aware that I should move the majority of this code to my service, but I plan to refactor once I have fixed the issue)

Comment: can you share the api response?

Comment: [{…}]
0:
0: {id: 2013, name: "Série A"}
1: {id: 2021, name: "Premier League"}
2: {id: 2016, name: "Championship"}
3: {id: 2018, name: "European Championship"}
4: {id: 2001, name: "UEFA Champions League"}
5: {id: 2015, name: "Ligue 1"}
6: {id: 2002, name: "Bundesliga"}
7: {id: 2019, name: "Serie A"}
8: {id: 2003, name: "Eredivisie"}
9: {id: 2017, name: "Primeira Liga"}
10: {id: 2014, name: "Primera Division"}
11: {id: 2000, name: "FIFA World Cup"}
ident: "competitions"
name: "com"

Comment: The length of the outer array element is 1 (which I believe may be causing the issue), but as you can see there are 12 items in the inner array.

Comment: Could you post the stringified response, the console log response makes it a bit weird, and don't know the full structure, i.e is there some nested array or not? please provide the result from `console.log(JSON.stringify(compsList))`

Comment: [{"0":{"id":2013,"name":"Série A"},"1":{"id":2021,"name":"Premier League"},"2":{"id":2016,"name":"Championship"},"3":{"id":2001,"name":"UEFA Champions League"},"4":{"id":2018,"name":"European Championship"},"5":{"id":2015,"name":"Ligue 1"},"6":{"id":2002,"name":"Bundesliga"},"7":{"id":2019,"name":"Serie A"},"8":{"id":2003,"name":"Eredivisie"},"9":{"id":2017,"name":"Primeira Liga"},"10":{"id":2014,"name":"Primera Division"},"11":{"id":2000,"name":"FIFA World Cup"}}]

Comment: @tillyno2 - This response isn't in proper format, list items aren't in an array but are in an object. Check out my edited answer, and change the `subscribe()` method as shown. It should work.

Comment: @Nikhil, I will play around with your answer, but in its current form, it does not work. It throws a few errors, firstly, [tslint] for (... in ...) statements must be filtered with an if statement (forin). In addtion, I note you are using response.push(...), if I am pushing an array for competitionsList, why not competitionsList.push(...)?

Comment: @tillyno2 - Yes, that is what I intended to do. That's a typo, it should be `competitionsList.push()`. I now replaced `for...in` statement with  `Object.values()`

Comment: @Nikhil - many thanks! That's done the trick!

Comment: That's awesome @tillyno2! You're welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mentioned in the comments about `undefined` error. This indicates you are trying to render the view before the data is available. Use `*ngIf` on your element to only render it when data is available.

```
<mat-form-field *ngIf="competitionsList">

</mat-form-field>
```

When you are iterating over the array using `*ngFor` you don't need to use the index `i`.

Replace `{{ comp[i].name }}` with `{{ comp.name }}`.

Then your  code will look like

```
  <mat-form-field *ngIf="competitionsList">
    <mat-select placeholder="Select Competition">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let comp of competitionsList; let i = index" [value]="comp">
        {{ comp.name }}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
```

**Live demo on StackBlitz:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-with-angular-v5-eukdkc

**EDIT:** You should format your response `compList` to form `competitionsList` array.

Change your `subscribe()` method to

```
.subscribe(
   compsList => {
      this.competitionsList = Object.values(compList[0]);
   });
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but that does not work. When I use the code as you suggested, it outputs a single value "comp" which exists in the outer array. I used the  {{ comp[i].name }} to get to the inner array to display in the drop down, Serie A, Premier League, etc

Comment: @tillyno2 - Can you update your question with value of `competitionsList` in proper legible format as JSON?

Comment: I had tried that already also (apologies I should have mentioned in my original question). But when I use competitionsList[0], I get a type error: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Comment: Okay, this error is indicating that `competitonsList` is undefined. Make sure you are not rendering the view before data is available. I'll update my answer with fix to this error.

Comment: @tillyno2 - Check out my edited answer. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: I now get a new error                   
SelectDropdownComponent.html:3 ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'com'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays. So it looks like it is not reading my observable as an array.. I have updated my original question to include my service and typescript function

Comment: Yes, that's right @tillyno2. But based on your updated code, looks like `competitonList` is just one array. Try changing `competitonsList[0]` to `competitonsList`.

Comment: when I change to competitonList is just returns "comp" as the only value in the dropdown.

Comment: Can you replace `[value]="comp"` with `[ngValue]="comp"`, looks like `[value]` cannot take objects.

Comment: I had tried this one before too :), this gives another error: Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'ngValue' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-option'.

Comment: @tillyno2 - Okay, let's stick with `[value]`. I'll try to reproduce this on StackBlitz and play around to figure out what is going wrong. Meanwhile, let's see if someone else figures it out and answers.

Comment: @tillyno2 - Looks like `[value]` can take objects as well. Also the code I have in my answer is working. You can see it live on my StackBlitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-with-angular-v5-eukdkc.